# why 404 error is not invoking when i am providing ID which is not exist

Tags: javascript, promise, endpoint, rest

```js
app.get('/tasks/:id',(req,res)=>{
    const _id= req.params.id

    Task.findById(_id).then((task)=>{
        if(!task){
        return res.status(404).send()
        }
        res.send(task)
        
    }).catch((e)=>{

        res.status(500).send()
    })
```

Comment: That seems correct to me. If an ID does not exist then a 404 is a good response.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Re-read the title ;) _"why 404 error is **not** invoking..."_

Comment: What is `task`? Is it something [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) when there's no result for an id?

Comment: @Andreas  - well then